# Best practises to speed up join tables on datetime range

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have two tables that have datetime ranges (`date_from`, `date_to`). What is the best approach to join that tables on condition that check if `date_from` to `date_to` range on first table overlaps datetime range on the second table ?

I've converted datetime columns to milliseconds and created index on it. I have query like below, but works not so fast (about 100 000 rows in both tables). Any suggestions to speed up this kind of query ?

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 
ON t2.id = (
   /* TOP 1: need to get only first matched row */
   SELECT TOP 1 id FROM t2 WHERE t2.date_from >= t1.date_from 
                             AND t2.date_from <= t1.date_to
)
```

Comment: That condition does not look like it is testing an overlap of the 2 ranges. I'd expect something like t2.date_from BETWEEN t1.date_from AND t1.date_to OR t2.date_to BETWEEN t1.date_from AND t1.date_to. Another issue is that TOP 1 without an ORDER BY... looks like it might be a bit unpredictable.

Comment: Yes, my mistake in WHERE. Corrected this (To simply I'm testing only that range in t2 starts inside t1 range). Thank You for `ORDER BY`

Comment: As for speed, I wouldn't know. Try Gareth's answer. Make sure to check the query plans. How big are the tables? How long does the execution take?

Comment: Post the query plan.  Without that, this question is like: "I drive a white 2011 Toyota Camry.  How can I shorten my commute?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the top 1 row from t2, I'd suggest using [CROSS APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    t1
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 *
            FROM    t2
            WHERE   t2.date_from >= t1.date_from 
            AND     t2.date_from <= t1.date_to
            ORDER BY t2.date_from -- GET FIRST RECORD
        ) t2;
```

It essentially means you can combine your join and your subquery into a single operation. I think the fact that you are using `SELECT *` could be costly as well, it means that even though your date columns are indexed you will have to do a lookup to retrieve all the data from t2, if you need all the data from both tables then this is a necessary evil, but if you don't then you may be able to simplify the execution plan.

Comment: Adding `ORDER BY ...` that You and @Frazz suggested me speed up the query vastly even without `CROSS APPLY`. Big THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
          start               end
            |                  |
A  <----->  |                  |
B      <----|----->            |
C    <------|------------------|---->
D           |   <----------->  |
E           |          <-------|-->
F           |                  |   <----->
            |                  |
```

The scenarios that overlap our start and end dates are B, C, D and E. Conversely A and F do not overlap.

Notice anything consistent between the two groups?

All the ones that overlap **begin before the `end`** and **finish after the `start`**

Therefore to get the overlaps the pseudo-SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
 INNER
  JOIN other_table
    ON other_table.start_date <= your_table.end_date
   AND other_table.end_date   >= your_table.start_date
```

Comment: Down-voted because? I added this because the query in the question has a where clause that doesn't look to be correct IMO.

Comment: He did have a problem in the WHERE, and he corrected it. But his question is about how to speed this thing up. Your explanation is very clear, but it does not answer the question IMHO.